# OneToOne Unidirectional cascade={"persist", "remove"} not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

On my symfony project I have a problem with 2 entities linked by a unidirectionnal OneToOne relationship. My entities are : Club and Address, a Club can have an address. See entity declaration bellow :

**Club Entity**

```
class Club{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FFPM\MainBundle\Entity\Address", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
protected $address;

...

}
```

**Address Entity**

```
class Address{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

...

}
```

For some reason when I remove a Club the Address stays in database. I tried with orphanRemoval and cascade{"remove"} and I can't get it to work even if I'm pretty sure it's some simple mistake.

Comment: did you update your db schema ? (not sure which one, but one of does delete annotations needs a schema update if i recal correctly, i was stuck on thisfor a second once before) Not sure if this is the case here, but try it

Answer (score 1):

Try use this construction:

```
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FFPM\MainBundle\Entity\Address", mappedBy="entidad", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=true)
     **/
    private $personaFisica;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm pretty sure that if I do that, everytime I delete an Address it will delete the club. But I wan't the exact opposite.

onDelete="CASCADE" is supposed to be on the inversed side. I don't have one since I'm on a unidirectionnal relationshp

Answer (score 1):

The relation OneToOne unidirectionnal in doctrine manage only the one side since you don't complete the relation. so there is two way you can persist or remove address entity, is that you use the domain Event listener or you manage your entity manually. And unfortunately both cases are not good practice.